# How to store data after popping a storyboard instantiated view controller to then repush it to the navigation controller stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have my `UIViewController`s mostly setup using a Storyboard file. In some cases I use the usual pattern of a `UINavigationController` in combination with `UITableViewController` to let the user dig into configuration details of the application. Each table view cell causes another view controller to be pushed onto the navigation stack (when the cell is selected) and users can go back to the overview table view controller using the navigation controller's back button.

I have the overview UITableViewController and the detail `UIViewController`s set up in the Storyboard, including the connections between them using segues.

Most of it works as expected, when I select a table view cell in the overview the correct detail view controller is pushed onto the navigation stack. But if I then change some views in the detail view controller and go back (possibly because I want to look something up)(thus the detail view controller is popped) and then press the same cell again, the views are reset to their original state and the data I put in is lost.

Of course I could save that data in the overview controller when the detail controller is popped and restore it when it is pushed again, but I wonder whether that is the best way.

In the past, I would have constructed the detail view controller myself and stored it in an instance variable. Then, if I had to push it again, I would push the exact same object (not just an instance of the same class) which would mean that it also saved the state of the view.

But as far as I can tell, using Storyboards, for each segue a new view controller is instantiated, so no data is kept. I also cannot set the `destinationViewController` property of the segue in `prepareforSegue:sender:` since it is read-only.

Is there a way to reuse an already created view controller in a segue?
Or is there some other elegant way to store the data to reuse it when the detail controller is pushed again? Ideally something the overview table view controller does not have to know about, since it would have to do store the data for all detail view controller in that case.

I know I could retrieve the view controller from the storyboard, instantiate it myself and push it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, but I like the segues and the overview of the view structure the storyboard provides, so I would like to keep that, if possible.

**Update**:
I think my description was a bit unclear. I do save the data, already, but currently it is saved in the detail view controller (it's not just "saved" by being in the view, I am not trying to abuse the view to store my data), so going back is an implicit "save my current state in this view" in my case. The problem is, I can't implement that in an easy way without storing the data in the overview controller IN ADDITION to storing it in the detail view controller. And I don't want to store it in the overview controller since it is data that belongs to the detail view controller and should be managed by it.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course I could save that data in the overview controller when the detail controller is popped and restore it when it is pushed again, but I wonder whether that is the best way.

I think that is the best way. If the detail view controller is being used to edit the data, generally accepted practice is that the user can only leave it by either saving the data or canceling their changes.

Comment: I see. I already save the data, but currently it is saved in the detail view controller (it's not just "saved" by being in the view. maybe that was a bit unclear), so going back is an implicit "save my current state in this view" in my case. The problem is, I can't implement that in an easy way without storing the data in the overview controller IN ADDITION to storing it in the detail view controller.

Comment: Yes, but what I am saying is "save my current state in this view" is not standard iOS user interface design. Standard practice is that when a user leaves a detail view controller after making a change, they should either know that they are making a change to the underlying model or they should know they are canceling that change and not saving the changes to the underlying model.

Comment: ok, so from a usability perspective I could think about adding a save button the user has to actively use to save data. But that doesn't change the problem. If the user presses the save button, I would still pop the view controller and display some kind of summary in the overview controller. Then, when the user selects it again to modify the data, I would want to show the same data they saw before. I store the data in the view controller so everything would be fine if I could reuse that already existing view controller.

Comment: You want to keep your data model separate from your view controllers. The data needs to be persisted somehow, either in NSUserDefaults, or a file, or a network-attached server, or CoreData, etc. The view controllers should get the information to show from your data model. This provides a nice separation and allows different view controllers to share data and show just the portion of the data that is needed.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation and normally I would agree completely. But in this case it does not have to be persisted, it only needs to be saved until the user is done putting in all the data after which it is send of to a server. Also, I might want to save things like which field had focus last time, that I don't want to save in the data model. Yes I could store all that in the user defaults and other places, it just seems like a lot of overhead, if there was just a way to keep the view controller around, which does have all that information.